# How To Center Text In QTextTable

Tags: c++, qt

I’m developing applications with qt framework and right now I want to save my tabular data to pdf. I'm using QTextTable and QTextDocument classes. However I can’t center text in cells. How should I do it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do the alignment as you are inserting the text, you can call this function with alignment = Qt:AlignHCenter. You can modify the function to also specify the character formatting.

```
// Insert text with specified alignment in specified cell
void insertAlignedText(QTextTable *table, int row, int col, Qt::Alignment alignment, QString text)
{
    // Obtain cursor and current block format
    QTextCursor textCursor = table->cellAt(row,col).firstCursorPosition();    
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = textCursor.blockFormat();

    // Read vertical part of current alignment flags
    Qt::Alignment vertAlign = blockFormat.alignment() & Qt::AlignVertical_Mask;

    // Mask out vertical part of specified alignment flags
    Qt::Alignment horzAlign = alignment & Qt::AlignHorizontal_Mask;

    // Combine current vertical and specified horizontal alignment
    Qt::Alignment combAlign = horzAlign | vertAlign;

    // Apply and write
    blockFormat.setAlignment(combAlign);    
    textCursor.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);
    textCursor.insertText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
QTextBlockFormat centerAlignment;
centerAlignment.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

cursor = table->cellAt(row, column).firstCursorPosition();
cursor.setBlockFormat(centerAlignment);
cursor.insertText("Hello, this is my first post here!");
```

But take care that alignment when set once is valid until the next change. That means that if you have, for example, two columns in a table, one with left alignment and one with right alignment and you are adding row by row to the table, you have to call [QTextCursor::setBlockFormat()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcursor.html#setBlockFormat) for every cell to alternate left and right alignment.

Answer (score 0):

See [QTextTable::setFormat](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qtexttable.html#setFormat), [QTextTableFormat::setAlignment](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qtexttableformat.html#setAlignment), [QTextTableCell::setFormat](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qtexttablecell.html#setFormat) and [QTextCharFormat::setVerticalAlignment](http://doc.troll.no/4.7/qtextcharformat.html#setVerticalAlignment). Alternatively, you could look into [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/stylesheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the alignment after the text has been written, you could use the following function with alignment = Qt:AlignHCenter.

```
// Modify horizontal alignment of text in specified cell
void modifyTextAlignment(QTextTable *table, int row, int col, Qt::Alignment alignment)
{
    // Obtain cursor and current block format
    QTextCursor textCursor = table->cellAt(row,col).firstCursorPosition();   
    textCursor.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = textCursor.blockFormat();

    // Read vertical part of current alignment flags
    Qt::Alignment vertAlign = blockFormat.alignment() & Qt::AlignVertical_Mask;

    // Mask out vertical part of specified alignment flags
    Qt::Alignment horzAlign = alignment & Qt::AlignHorizontal_Mask;

    // Combine current vertical and specified horizontal alignment
    Qt::Alignment combAlign = horzAlign | vertAlign;

    // Apply
    blockFormat.setAlignment(combAlign);    
    textCursor.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 equivalent solution to this question **(How To Center Text In QTextTable)**.This also works for merged cells.

```
centerAlignment = PyQt5.QtGui.QTextBlockFormat()
centerAlignment.setAlignment(PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
cursor = table.cellAt(row, column).firstCursorPosition()
cursor.setBlockFormat(centerAlignment)
cursor.insertText("Hello, this is the PyQt5 code equivalent to this question!")
```