# Qt::AlignVCenter does not work on QTextTable

Tags: qt, qt4, alignment, qt5

I created QTextTable:

```
QTextDocument *document=new QTextDocument(this);
QTextCursor cursor(document);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);

QTextTableCellFormat cellFormat;
cellFormat.setLeftPadding(7);
cellFormat.setRightPadding(7);

QBrush blackBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
tableFormat.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
tableFormat.setBorderBrush(blackBrush);
tableFormat.setBorder(0.5);
tableFormat.setCellSpacing(0);
tableFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Solid);
tableFormat.setWidth(QTextLength(QTextLength::PercentageLength, 100));
QTextTable *table = cursor.insertTable(10,10,tableFormat);

QTextBlockFormat centerAlignment;
centerAlignment.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

table->mergeCells(0,0,10,5);
cursor = table->cellAt(0, 0).firstCursorPosition();
cursor.setBlockFormat(centerAlignment);
cursor.insertText("text");
```

I want to write text in the middle of cell vertically and horizontally
But my text is in the middle horizontally but it is not in the middle vertically.
Also Qt::AlignVCenter and Qt::AlignBottom do not work. 
I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329809/1997790 but it is not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using QTextCharFormat::setVerticalAlignment(), as in:

```
QTextTableCell   cell = table->cellAt(0, 0);
QTextCharFormat  cellFormat = cell.format();

cellFormat.setVerticalAlignment(QTextCharFormat::AlignMiddle);
cell.setFormat(cellFormat);
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to try using [style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview) to customize the table.

Comment: Thank you @piccy, you solved my problem. But there is no setVerticalCellAlignment().It should be setVerticalAlignment().